# Cannot use URLRequestMethod different from POST GET in ActionScript

Tags: actionscript-3, post, actionscript, get

I'm trying to get the head of a page without downloading the whole thing, because it's too heavy and I just need the header information.

The code is this:

```
var resource:String = "<myResource>";
var urlRequest : URLRequest = new URLRequest(resource);
urlRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.HEAD;
var requestLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
requestLoader.load(urlRequest);
```

It works if I use either POST or GET, but not HEAD, PUT or DELETE.

I don't know how to solve it or if it has been deprecated.

According to the [docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLRequestMethod.html), the constant is still valid but in the first line it says that it is only to distinguish between GET and POST.

Edit:
Finally I ended up doing the request in Javascript and calling it from actionScript. Maybe it is not a great solution, but it works fine.